# Preventing source blocks to generate agents if destination is occupied

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to create a packaging cell for 5 items into 1 package; the 5 items are picked up from a resource (worker) and placed into a packaging machine which generate the package; a conveyor moves the packages from the machine to a buffer and every once in a while (say every 20 packages) the worker stops picking the items and goes to the buffer the put all the packages in a box, ideally ready to be shipped. Once the worker has completed the box he has to go back to his pick&place task.

Now, my issues are:

1. When the worker stops picking the items from the rackSystem and goes to the buffer, the source blocks have to stop generating agents, otherwise the simulation will stop saying that there are no available cells in the rack;
2. When the worker gets back to his picking task the source blocks have to start generating agents again.

With the hold blocks in the picture I managed to stop the source blocks when the worker stops picking from the rack, anyway I could not make the process start again when the box is complete. How can i do this?

Everything works fine except from the fact that once the worker returns to the picking location and take the last 5 items from the rack, no more agents are allowed to enter the rack.

[image: Main_image]

Comment: This is what i'm typing in the hold blocks:

Mode: Conditional
Blocking condition: rackSystem.hasSpace() == false

Answer (score 0):

Actually from this setup, I think you should do this:

1. Let your sources create agents continuously. In reality (I suppose) things also do not stop coming in just because the worker is doing something else.
2. Gather all agents in an infinite queue, as you do
3. remove the hold blocks
4. instead, make your RackStore and RackPick objects utilize the worker resource pool (tick the box as below and select your resource pool)

[image]

You may need to play with the "customize resource choice" selection as well to ensure that your worker only tries to store items when the RackSystem has a space, though, something like below:

[image]

Comment: My rackPick blocks already utilize the resource pool, not the rackStore ones though (that's because in reality that task is not assigned to the same worker).  I'll try using the customize resource choice, i didn't think about that option. The main reason for introducing the hold blocks (and generally for stopping the source blocks generating agents) is that i keep getting the same error "no cell available in the rack" when i run the model. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I know, the "no cell available in the rack" is a pain. Sorry for sending you in different directions all the time. Have you tried replacing the queues with "Wait" objects. Also remove the hold objects. And only OnExit of RackPick (after the agent has left the rack system) do you call "myWaitObject.free(1)". That should work well in your case

Comment: No worries. I tried with the wait blocks but it told me that "the method free(agent) in the type Wait is not applicable :( I didn't quite understand what that meant so i got back to the queue-hold structure.